# Subtract dates in XSLT

Tags: date, xslt, xslt-1.0, subtraction

I have dates in format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I am using `XSLT 1.0`. How we can find the difference between two dates .i.e number of days between the two entered dates.
Have tried using `dayTimeDuration`, `days-from-duration`. Nothing is working out. Also tried simply subtracting the dates using `xs:date`

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't have date processing functions. You would need to use a custom function of some sort, and how to do that would highly depend on what you're using to run the XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Types and functions such as `dayTimeDuration`, `days-from-duration` require XSLT 2.0. Consider upgrading.

Alternatively, the EXSLT date-and-time library of extension functions (see exslt.org) might be available for your chosen processor.